# Django: reading from STATIC_ROOT during testing

Tags: django, testing, static

I render some pdf from some templates in my project. Well, it seems to work, but...

...I wanna test it!

Problem is that some files I read during rendering are in STATIC_ROOT - so I need to collectstatic when I run tests (kinda wierd!).

Question is: is there a way to work with STATIC_ROOT during testing, but without 'real' collecting static?

Comment: Just curious why would you ever wanna have files there in development?

Comment: @ArgsKwargs For example, to test js/css compressor/processor.

Comment: @DrTyrsa I don't really see why you need to access the collection to test that behaviour, am I missing something? I've used a custom Command to test LESS compilation in development for example

Comment: @ArgsKwargs Sometimes I just want to test "as close as possible" to production. May be it's a matter of taste, but why not, anyway. :-)

Comment: @DrTyrsa yea I understand, but then I usually run a apache/lighttpd/nginx instance locally :-)

Comment: @ArgsKwargs I have a template to generate pdf files. Plus some fonts for them. It seems to me, that the django-way is to create a variable in settings, for example CONTRACT_PDF_TEMPLATE (okay, it is a template) and CONTRACT_PDF_FONT_DIR (okay, there is not need to put it in static).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use following way. In you project directory create a file named `dev_static_finder.py` with these contents.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.contrib.staticfiles.finders import BaseStorageFinder
from django.conf import settings

class StaticRootFinder(BaseStorageFinder):
    storage = FileSystemStorage(settings.STATIC_ROOT, settings.STATIC_URL)
```

Add this line to your `settings.py`

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS += ('dev_static_finder.StaticRootFinder',)
```

I don't know an easer way.